# "Find" on the WebBrowser's context menu does not work

Tags: webbrowser-control

When I embed Microsoft's ActiveX control "WebBrowser" into my application and add a line:

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />`

to force it using "Edge" then (and only then!) does the "Find" command in the context menu do not work: I can select it, the dialog box pops up but when I enter a single character that **does** appear somewhere on the page it immediately shows "not found".

Surely somebody must have run into this but I cannot find anything on the Internet. Anybody?!

This is a link to a sample Visual Studio project that demonstrates the problem:

https://drive.google.com/a/aplteam.com/file/d/0B3VhiTAx8vLYSkdDdlF0bUtNbFE/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record: I found that it does **not** work when I assign the HTML in memory via the "document" object. If I write the HTML to a temp file and navigate to that temp file then it **does** work...